# tab index is not working for date picker (AngularJS)

Tags: css, angularjs, html, datepicker, tabindex

I have added tabindex=1,2 and 3 respectively for the screenshot shown below. But, tab index 1 opens the calendar 1 and doesnt close it and hence 2 doesn't work and tab index 3 opens search. How do I resolve this?

[image]

```html
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 search-date heightSixty" id="arrivalDate">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary calendar-div"
                            tabindex="4" id="one"
                            ng-click="vm.arrivalDtOpen($event)"
                            datepicker-popup="{{'MMM d'}}"
                            ng-model="vm.searchRQ.arrivalDate"
                            is-open="vm.arrivalDtOpened"
                            ng-change="vm.arrivalDateChange()"
                            datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                            show-weeks="false"
                            current-text="Reset To Today's Date"
                            ng-focus=vm.arrivalDtOpen($event)"
                        >
                        <div class="calendar-date-font" title="Select Starting Arrival Date">
                            {{ vm.searchRQ.arrivalDate | date : 'MMM' }}</br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="calendar-date">
                            {{  vm.searchRQ.arrivalDate | date : 'd' }}
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 search-date heightSixty" id="departureDate">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary calendar-div"
                            tabindex="5" id="two"
                            ng-click="vm.departureDtOpen($event)"
                            datepicker-popup="{{'MMM d'}}"
                            ng-model="vm.searchRQ.departureDate"
                            is-open="vm.departureDtOpened"
                            ng-change="vm.departureDateChange()"
                            datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                            ng-focus="vm.departureDtOpen($event)"
                            show-weeks="false"
                            current-text="Reset To Today's Date">

                        <div class="calendar-date-font" title="Select Ending Arrival Date">
                            {{ vm.searchRQ.departureDate | date : 'MMM' }}</br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="calendar-date">
                            {{ vm.searchRQ.departureDate | date : 'd' }}
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 search-icon heightSixty">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary search-button" placeholder=" " title="Search" id="btn-search"
                            ng-click="vm.retrieveReservation(searchReservationVm.searchRQ)">
                        <div tabindex="6" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon-bg" id="searchImg"
                             ng-focus="vm.departureDtClose($event)">
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </div>
```